# How to fix TypeError: this.state.Templatelist.map is not a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display JSON data that is coming from webapi. I need to fill  dropdown with the data in REACT. I am getting the issue while filling the data in .

console.log(this.state.Templatelist) returns the data. this data is coming from api.

[{"Template_ID":11,"TemplateName":"All"},{"Template_ID":21,"TemplateName":"Test"}]

Please find my code:

```
import React from "react";
export class test extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                    CopyFromTemplate_ID: "",
                    Templatelist: [],
             }
             this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       }

       handleChange(event) {
             this.setState({ CopyFromTemplate_ID: event.target.value });

             console.log(event.target.value)

       }
 
       componentDidMount() {
                  this.getTemplateList();
       }

       getTemplateList() {
             fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                           this.setState({
                                 Templatelist: data,
                                 loading: false
                           })
                           console.log(this.state.Templatelist);
                    })
       }

       render() {
             return (
                    <div>
                           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                                 {this.state.Templatelist}
                         <select size="1" value={this.state.CopyFromTemplate_ID} onChange={this.handleChange} >
       <option></option>
      {this.state.Templatelist.map((item) =>
          <option id={item.Template_ID} value={item.Template_ID}>
              {item.value}
         </option>)
      }
  </select>
</form>
</div>
);

    }

}


export default test;
```

Thanks

Comment: This occurs when `Templatelist` is not an array and therefore doesn't have map available on it. Check the typeof Templatelist before mapping to see the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is undefined or waiting to arrive, you need to check if it is an array before you render it. You can check if data arrived and if it has a length, if not, then render the loading component.

```
  {this.state.Templatelist.length? this.state.Template.map((item) =>
          <option id={item.Template_ID} value={item.Template_ID}>
              {item.value}
         </option>) : <p>...loading</p>
      }
```

Comment: I tried the solution for checking the length. Its still giving the same issue.  console.log(this.state.TemplateList} shows [{"Template_ID":11,"TemplateName":"All"},{"Template_ID":21,"TemplateName":"Test"}]

Comment: console.log(typeof(TemplateList) is undefined. console.log(typeof(data)) is string. console.log(typeof(this.state.TeplateList)) is string too. What needs to be done. Please help.

Comment: Seems like your data object is a string of some sort. Can you console.log(data)  in .then(data => ...)

Comment: console.log(data) returns [{"Template_ID":11,"TemplateName":"All"},{"Template_ID":21,"TemplateName":"Test"}]